# Is it valid to categorize a pre-intervention score as the independent variable when the post-intervention score is part of the outcome variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I received a study proposal in which an individual wants to study the correlation between pre-intervention scores and post-intervention scores.

As part of the study, all participants would undergo the same intervention on a single day. A survey would be given to obtain the baseline activity score (0 to 100) and then the same survey would be given 5 days after the intervention. Their hypothesis is that the distribution of baseline scores would create 3 groups, a majority of scores would be ~100 (group 1), some would be ~50-75 (group 2) and the rest would be close to 0 (group 3).

The proposed outcome variable (binary) is whether the change score (y2 - y1) is < 0, considered a "recovery" from the intervention.

Am I correct in thinking that it is not possible to test whether the 3 groups have differing odds of having the binary outcome ("recovery")?

Comment: The proposed dependent variable Y is an idiotic arbitrary information losing transformation of the original measurements.

Comment: See https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/responder-analysis-loser-x-4 for details